# Error importing "dexie-export-import" in Angular

Tags: angular, dexie

I am trying to use dexie-export-import with Angular. But I get the error **Module not found: Error: Can not resolve 'stream' in 'xxx\node_modules\ dexie-export-import\dist'**. I have tried and googled different ways but I really can not find the way to make it work.

I'm working with angular 7.2, dexie 2.0.4 and dexie-export-import 1.0.0-alpha.9

```js
import Dexie from 'dexie';
import 'dexie-export-import';

export class TestDatabase extends Dexie {
  testTable: Dexie.Table<PersistableTest, number>;

  constructor() {
    super('test-database');
    this.version(1).stores({
      testTable: '++id'
    });

    this.testTable.mapToClass(PersistableTest);

    this.export();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be an issue with the rollup script.

I just published a new version on npm that should not include the dependency to stream. Try:

```
npm install dexie-export-import@1.0.0-alpha.10
```

Please let me know if this solves it!

Comment: Well, this solves the dependency problem!
The problem I have now is that it gives an error in runtime because it does not find the export method.
Even based on the same code of the original question.
One solution I found was adding **"dexie-export-import": ["node_modules/dexie-export-import/dist/dexie-export-import.js"]**
inside compilerOprions / paths in the tsconfig.json file, 
this is good?